# What is the mixpanel equivalent in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, analytics, mixpanel

I am learning more about AWS and I have learnt that they offer a lot of services that may be of great value. The problem however is that I do not know about all this services and since I am already using AWS, it is easier to just integrate AWS services rather than using different ones outside the AWS ecosystem.

I was wondering what is mixpanel equivalent in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think where is a "equivalent" service. But there is services around the scope of observability.

Here is a link with listed services for observability:

https://aws.amazon.com/products/management-and-governance/use-cases/monitoring-and-observability/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc&blog-posts-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&blog-posts-cards.sort-order=desc

I hope this helps you.